# Is there a way to create Container Group with diagnostics and identity configs in Azure using latest .NET Core SDK

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, f#

Problem is creating Container group with identity and log analytics diagnostics in Azure using .NET SDK with nugets

- Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent
- Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance
- Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent

So the question is:

1. Is there a way to create container group in Azure with identity and diagnostics specified using latest .NET Core SDK fluent API?

OR

2. Is there a way to create plain constructor built container group in Azure using latest .NET Core SDK?

There are plenty of examples to use the fluent API eg.

```cs
// Create the container group
var containerGroup = azure.ContainerGroups.Define(containerGroupName)
    .WithRegion(azureRegion)
    .WithExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroupName)
    .WithLinux()
    .WithPublicImageRegistryOnly()
    .WithoutVolume()
    .DefineContainerInstance(containerGroupName + "-1")
        .WithImage(containerImage)
        .WithExternalTcpPort(80)
        .WithCpuCoreCount(1.0)
        .WithMemorySizeInGB(1)
        .Attach()
    .WithDnsPrefix(containerGroupName)
    .Create();
```

Although, I haven't found a way to declare identity or diagnostics to this container group.

On the other hand I found a way to create ContainerGroup object with class constructors (yes, my code is in F#):

```ml
// Create containers
let containers =
    [| minCount .. maxCount |]
    |> Array.map (fun i ->
        Container(
            name = (sprintf "%s-%i" containerName i),
            image = image, 
            resources = resources, 
            EnvironmentVariables = envVariables))

// Create container group for containers
let containerGroup =
    ContainerGroup(
        containers = containers, 
        osType = "linux", 
        name = groupName, 
        location = location, 
        identity = identity, // missing from fluent
        imageRegistryCredentials = imageCredentials, 
        restartPolicy = restartType, 
        diagnostics = diag) // missing from fluent
```

However, with these plain constructor built objects, I haven't found a method to create them in Azure.

Comment: You can try to use [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/containergroups/createorupdate#containergroupidentity) to set identity and diagnostics in C# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to to send the plain constructor built objects to azure using `ContainerInstanceManagementClient` function from assembly `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance`.

```ml
let creds = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(client, key, tenant, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
let client = new ContainerInstanceManagementClient(creds)
client.SubscriptionId <- subscriptionId
let _ =
    client.ContainerGroups.CreateOrUpdate(
        resourceGroupName = rgName,
        containerGroupName = name,
        containerGroup = containerGroup) // Container group from the question
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance package is now deprecated I switched to the Azure.ResourceManager but had a similar problem. After some debugging I found that the credentials of the ArmClient are not propagated to the Docker registry pull request, you have to do that explicitly by adding a ImageRegistryCredentials, see code below. It might be a good thing once you know, because now you can use different credentials for pulling the Docker image.

```
var credential = (TokenCredential)new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, user, clientSecret);
var armClient = new ArmClient(credential);
var subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
var resourceGroup = (await subscription.GetResourceGroupAsync(resourceGroupName).ConfigureAwait(false)).Value;
var containerGroups = resourceGroup.GetContainerGroups();
var resourceRequirements = new ContainerResourceRequirements(new ContainerResourceRequestsContent(8, 2));
var container = new ContainerInstanceContainer(containerGroupName, containerImage, resourceRequirements);
var containerGroupData = new ContainerGroupData(AzureLocation.WestEurope,
    new List<ContainerInstanceContainer> { container }, ContainerInstanceOperatingSystemType.Linux);
var registryCredential = new ContainerGroupImageRegistryCredential(containerRegistry, user)
    {
        Password = clientSecret
    };
containerGroupData.ImageRegistryCredentials.Add(registryCredential);
var containerGroup = await containerGroups.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, containerGroupName,
    containerGroupData);
await containerGroup.Value.StartAsync(WaitUntil.Completed);
```